# ASP.NET MVC lazy loading not working with ICollection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have created an auction web site with these two models:

```
public class ItemModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ItemModelId { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
    public DateTime DateCreatedUtc { get; set; }

    ...

    [ForeignKey("AcceptedBidModel")]
    public int? AcceptedBidModelId { get; set; }

    public virtual BidModel AcceptedBidModel { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BidModel> ItemBids { get; set; }
}

public class BidModel
{
    [Key]
    public int BidModelId { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
    public DateTime DateCreatedUtc { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(1, Int32.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "The bid must have a positive value")]
    public int Bid { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ItemModel")]
    public int ItemModelId { get; set; }

    public virtual ItemModel ItemModel { get; set; }
}
```

Everything was working fine with `ItemBids` being populated with data but when I added a `BidModel` to `ItemModel` (the bid that was accepted) `ItemBids` became empty.

```
[ForeignKey("BidModel")]
public int? BidModelId { get; set; }

public virtual BidModel BidModel { get; set; }
```

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: can you please show me the code where u are adding and its not sucess

Comment: How is your table designed? If its one-many relation between `BidModel` and `ItemModel` then having `ICollection <BidModel>` make sense, but having another `BidModel` property will change the behavior.

Comment: One `ItemModel` can have many `BidModel`, but I wanted to have another `BidModel` in the `ItemModel` for the accepted bid. Is this not possible? Somehow lazy loading gets confused when I added that extra `BidModel`.

Comment: Is there anything in `ItemModel`'s constructor?

Comment: No constructor at all @GertArnold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by removing the accepted bid (`AcceptedBidModel`) and created a bool in the `BidModel` indicating if the bid is the accepted one.

Here are the new models:

```
public class ItemModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ItemModelId { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
    public DateTime DateCreatedUtc { get; set; }

    ...

    public virtual ICollection<BidModel> ItemBids { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public BidModel AcceptedBid
    {
        get {
            return ItemBids.Where(s => s.Accepted).SingleOrDefault();
        }
        set {}
    }
}

public class BidModel
{
    [Key]
    public int BidModelId { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
    public DateTime DateCreatedUtc { get; set; }

    public bool Accepted { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(1, Int32.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "The bid must have a positive value")]
    public int Bid { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ItemModel")]
    public int ItemModelId { get; set; }

    public virtual ItemModel ItemModel { get; set; }
}
```